# What are horizontal and vertical design elements?

Tags: architecture, anti-patterns

I was going through [this article](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/jumble) on Architectural Anti-Patterns and it talks about `horizontal and vertical design elements` getting intermixed to form an unstable architecture.

I was not able to google the definition of these terms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Horizontal and Vertical elements as the author of the article defines them are

> "Vertical design elements are dependent upon the individual
>   application and specific software implementations. Horizontal design
>   elements are those that are common across applications and specific
>   implementations"

Usually the use of these terms is in the context of a single solution and then the roles are a little different where horizontal elements are those relating to a specific layer e.g. components for data access, UI element and vertical relate to cross cutting concerns like authentication, auditing etc.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise Horizontal talks about Technical/Framework related and vertical talks more about business functionality.